# WPF | C# - When WindowStyle = "None" and the window is maximized the Task Bar doesn't show up

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, taskbar

How can I be able to see the taskbar when `WindowStyle="None"`.  I'm trying to have my own buttons (Close, Maximize, Minimize) by removing the actual window title bar and using a dll too remove the border. Easy to maintain and easy to put in my code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941443/properly-maximizing-wpf-window-with-windowstyle-none .

Comment: What's the code you're using to implement your Maximize button click? Also I think that "border" you said you're using a dll to remove is probably the Resize handle, and there's a property to remove it. I can't remember what it's called, but check the window's Resize properties

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible fix to do this is: to limit the max size of window. For example:

C# code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
        {
            System.Drawing.Rectangle rec = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromHandle(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle).WorkingArea;
            MaxHeight = rec.Height;
            MaxWidth = rec.Width;
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            MaxHeight = double.PositiveInfinity;
            MaxWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize;
            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to set maxsize just before changing of window state. Otherwise, in some cases it works wrong. Also don't forget about ResizeMode.

And xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" WindowStyle="None" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```