# Can't maximize MahApps.Metro window in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, mahapps.metro

Сan't maximize window when using MahApps.Metro window, the size does not change. Example of my window:

```xml
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Example.View.HelpView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Example.UserControls"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Height="843" 
        Width="1258" 
        WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent">
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

**Edit**

I created button for this and trying to change the state as follows:

```cs
private void UserControl_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Window _window = Window.GetWindow(this);
    if (_window.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
    {
        _window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
    else
    {
        _window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

When I expand the window to full screen, it behaves as follows, takes up the same space as in normal mode, but the rest of the window is locked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miHnt.png)

Comment: Maybe this will help? [Properly maximizing WPF window with WindowStyle=None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941443/properly-maximizing-wpf-window-with-windowstyle-none)

Comment: I have completed the answer

Comment: It did not help

Answer (score 0):

lastly do you try this :) I think "_window" not seting correctly now

```
xaml
        <controls:MetroWindow 
               x.name="MetroWindow"
    </controls:MetroWindow>
c#
Window _window = MetroWindow;

or

c#

    Window _window = (Window)sender;
```

Comment: it didn't help either