# How to suppress the ability to maximize of a resizable WPF window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, user-interface

I have a WPF application that has a Window that is with a WindowStyle of none, and is resizable.  I didn't want the user to be able to minimize or maximize the Window so I just didn't expose buttons for those operations.  This works well, but I just realized on Win7+ you can maximize a Windows simply by dragging it near the top of the screen.

Is there some way to suppress or override this behavior?  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to? WPF Window - Maximized, No Resize/Move](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318385/how-to-wpf-window-maximized-no-resize-move)

Comment: It's kind of the inverse of that question though.  I am not a dedicated WPF developer so what I tried was just not exposing the minimize/maximize buttons, which worked fine until the product started getting used on Windows 7.  I looked for a Maximize event to handle, but there is none.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
```

`WindowStyle="ToolWindow"` removes the Min/Max icons on the top right window corner. `ResizeMode="NoResize"` prevents the window from being resizable.

Comment: I have `WindowStyle="None"` right now as a requirement because we have  custom window UI conventions -- in said convention I just didn't include min/max buttons.  It also needs to be resizable.

Comment: Humm... probably in that case you can fix the MinWidhth/MaxWidth and MinHeight/MaxHeight to force a particular size.

Answer (score 0):

Pieced this together from a few other questions:

```
private void image_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
   {
      //This prevents win7 aerosnap
      if (this.ResizeMode != System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize)
      {
         this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
         this.UpdateLayout();
         DragMove();
         this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip;
      }
      else
         DragMove();
   }
}
```